# how to register the app to open the pdf file in my app in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

i want to open the pdf file in my app from pdf page,
but i am not getting any option of opening the pdf in my app.

this my info.plist file

```
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>PDF</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>     
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <string>com.neosofttech.pdf</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Owner</string>
</dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
   <array>
   <dict>
    <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>

<string>public.pdf</string>       
         </array>
    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
    <string>PDFReader File</string>
    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.neosofttech.pdf</string>
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <string>pdf</string>

    </dict>
</dict>
```

pls tell me where i am wrong in this, how can i open the pdf file in my app.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to open an attachment from within Mail based on your plist here. Since you don't own the PDF file type you can't declare it as an exported type. You only need to declare it as a supported document type.

For example:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

You can find a list of all of the system supplied content types [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) or in `UTCoreTypes.h`.

When someone does open a PDF file and chooses your application that file will be copied to an `Inbox` subdirectory of your `Documents` folder in your app sandbox. Your app will then be opened and within your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` your `launchOptions` dictionary will contain a `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` key specifying the URL of the file within your sandbox that you can then work with.

Comment: hi..i have used the same code..it was working properly...but now i am not able to see my application name in mail open in for pdf files..i am using the same code..which was working earlier..the only thing i changed is now i am using ios4.2 do we need to do any changes to implement the same in ios4.2. do you have any idea why this happens .?

Comment: Here's an update for iOS 4+, where apps can stay running in the background. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is only called if your application was not already running. To make sure you get the incoming file if your app is running, you can implement application:handleOpenURL: instead (or application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: in iOS 4.2+).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're trying to do unless you do the following:

- Register a custom url with the system
- Call that custom url from within a hyperlink inside the PDF
- Generate a PDF with clickable links

So what this means is that you [register a custom url handler](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) in your info.plist. For example, let's say you create a custom url handler with the form coolapp://. Now, inside of your document from which you generate the PDF, when you create a hyperlink, have it use your custom URL, for example coolapp://filedetails?pdfurl=mywebsite.com/path/to/pdffile.pdf&pageno=5. You then have to parse this in [-application:handleOpenURL:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleOpenURL:). Download the file specified in the *pdfurl* field and then jump to the page specified in *pageno*.

Keep in mind that this assumes you are creating the PDF in question yourself. If you do not control the PDF content creation process, you *cannot* do what you are wanting to do. There is no way to open your app from an arbitrary PDF. It has to be done using a custom URL.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Insert code below to info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>"*"</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Unknown</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: well, I mean, you're not wrong. This will register your app as a handler for every single file type, which probably isn't what most people will want

Answer (score 2):

Old post - but I landed on here also looking for a way to pass a PDF to my App.

The plist depicted by Ashley Clark help me to register my App as an App that can take a PDF file as a parameter. +1 for him on that one :-)

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

However, to fully implement this, I used the following method in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    NSLog(@"sourceApplication: %@", sourceApplication);
    NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
```

The above runs when the App is opened as I was running Safari and had a PDF that I wanted to share from there.

Above, I can determine which App passed my App the PDF and the URL to it's location.

When run, it outputs the following:

```
sourceApplication: com.apple.mobilesafari

url: file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C395439F-7A0D-434F-8D78-D4615DB643E1/data/Containers/Data/Application/E3B181BC-6075-4F2C-923D-2ECC642DA555/Documents/Inbox/pdf-5.pdf
```

I can then use the URL to open the PDF and do whatever I want with it in my App.