# upload pdf via iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, icloud

I have a web-service that transforms an uploaded pdf into a flipping-book. I wan't to create an iOS app that allows the user to upload their pdf and recieve the flipping-book. What possibilities are there to upload pdf from iPhone/iPad ?

Is it possible via iCloud? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably register your app to open pdf files from whatever sources (like from mail attachments), here's an example of how it is done: [how to register the app to open the pdf file in my app in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974285/how-to-register-the-app-to-open-the-pdf-file-in-my-app-in-ipad)