# How to see installed applications option in iphone/iPAD to open pdf file?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf

I have developed a pdf reader application.What I want that, when user TAP AND HOLD on PDF attachment(via email); iPhone/iPAD should show installed application options as menu(along with my application) to open the PDF.How can I do this? Could you please suggest me any link?

Note: as per apple document "Registering the file types your app supports", I did the changes in infoPlist.string like this:

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
 <string>PDF</string>
 <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
   <array>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
   </array>
  <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
     <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
   </array>
  <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
</dict>
```

But, its showing "Data could not be read because it is corrupted". How to resolve this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974285/how-to-register-the-app-to-open-the-pdf-file-in-my-app-in-ipad may help

Comment: Thank you! Could you please provide me a step by step way? Any link that can help?Asking, becoz I'm a biggner.

Comment: I'm changed my question.please help

Answer (score 2):

Nice blog see this it has step by step guide..

http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Comment: Seems to be helpful but bit complicated to begin with. :(

Comment: I'm changed my question.plese help