# How to add client certificate to https request in Swift (no ssl pinning)

Tags: swift

For the communication with a server API in my iOS app I have to include a client certificate (crt + key file) with every http request. So no ssl pinning, just include a certificate. My customer tells me to send the certificate with the session but don't know how to do this.

How can I do this in Swift ? Any advice / code snippet / example etc appreciated.

Thanks for your help
Frank

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870572/how-to-implement-client-certificates-and-server-authentication-for-ios

Comment: found this but still have to check if it works....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985856/getting-client-certificate-to-work-for-mutual-authentication-using-swift-3-and-a

Comment: Yes !! Found the solution in SO story mentioned above (answer Andrew Philips).